# Dropdown List not adding Items

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on implementing a `DropDownList` for a website (not my own website) and I can not get the `DropDownList` to populate any items. Bit frustrating but that's the life of a coder right? This is what I have for the code so far regarding the `DropDownList`. I have an understanding of C# but aspx and the bridge between them is new to me so I might of missed something obvious. Could someone steer me in the right direction?

**aspx file's DropDown Generation**

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dpdCategory" Width="200px"/>
```

**Init to ID in .cs file**

```
protected DropDownList dpdCategory;
```

**Function to Generate the Items**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dpdCategory.Items.Clear();
    this.dpdCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem("hello", "0"));
    this.dpdCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem("hello", "1"));
}
```

Comment: In page load event, try control page ispostback event.... Try again...

Comment: can you post the complete conent of .aspx and .aspx.cs files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to put it when the page is not posting back. Like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.dpdCategory.Items.Clear();
        this.dpdCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem("hello", "0"));
        this.dpdCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem("hello", "1"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Gave it a whirl and it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

```
  var categories = new List<ListItem>
                {
                    new ListItem("hello", "0"),
                    new ListItem("hello", "1")
                };

dpdCategory.DataTextField = "Text";
dpdCategory.DataValueField = "Value";
dpdCategory.DataSource = categories ;
dpdCategory.DataBind();
```

Comment: I would have thought it would work but sadly no change.

Comment: Your code looks allright. Are you able to stop your code if you put a breakpoint in Page_Load? Have you had a look in the *.aspx.designer.cs file as well?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to initialise dropdownlist in .cs file.

Then change your page load like this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dpdCategory.Items.Clear();
        dpdCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem("hello", "0"));
        dpdCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem("hello", "1"));
    }
```

This should work.

Comment: Sadly it did nothing. I have never seen a DropDown so reluctant to populate

Comment: Try to remove `protected DropDownList dpdCategory;` and rebuild the solution